# Strange behaviour with figure on chapter first page

Tags: graphics, chapters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

When I compile the following latex snippet:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{1}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Picture.PNG}
    \caption{Plug-in Landing Page }
    \label{fig:ASuRALP}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have a problem: The image is put to the next page. I have to reduce the size of the image a lot if I want it to fit in this chapter title page. The very strange behaviour that I observe is that at the human eye, the picture has clearly the place to fit into this first page, and if I put text instead of the picture, there is a lot of text that fits into the first page (a lot more than the picture size).

Does anyone has an idea of the problem ?

Comment: There may be "enough" from your point of view, but LaTeX judges differently. See this [excellent answer by Frank Mittelbach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/17198) on this matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The figure environment is a float. As default LaTeX will not put a float in the middle of the running text if it is larger than 0.2 of `\textheight` and it will not put it at the bottom of the page if it larger than 0.3 of `\textheight`. Also if will not move the float before the chapter title, so it is moved to the next page.

You can change this defaults. See https://texfaq.org/FAQ-floats

Comment: Thanks for the excellent pointers and reference, this solved the problem (and increased my knowledge of floats)

Answer (score 3):

I normally don't recommend overriding LaTeX's default settings for placing floating objects. However, you state that your "picture has clearly the place to fit into this first page"; hence, this looks like an instance where the LaTeX defaults are too conservative.

Rather than reset some of these float-related parameters yourself, you may want to simplify your life by loading the `float` package and affixing the `[H]` (note: not `[h]`) location specifier to `\begin{figure}`.